# Using RedisTagAwareAdapter in Symfony 4.4

Tags: symfony, caching, configuration, symfony-4.4

I have an issue getting Symfony to play nicely with a tag-aware adapter for redis

Unfortunately for me, Symfony 5.2 includes this feature, but as we're not switching to a non-lts version that's kind of out of the question. I have tried checking out the configuration, but it does not quite work for me.

Here's my current setup:

```yaml
# cache.yaml
framework:
  cache:
    prefix_seed: !php/const App\Kernel::APP_VERSION
    app: cache.adapter.redis_tag_aware
```

```yaml
  redis.cache_app:
    class: Redis
    factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
    arguments:
      - '%env(REDIS_DNS)%'

  cache.adapter.redis_tag_aware:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisTagAwareAdapter
    arguments:
      $redisClient: '@redis.cache_app'
      $marshaller: '@?cache.default_marshaller'
    calls:
      - ['setLogger', ['@?logger']]
    tags:
      - { name: cache.pool, provider: cache.default_redis_provider, clearer: cache.default_clearer, reset: reset }
      - { name: monolog.logger, channel: cache }
```

But it screams about argument 0 not existing via some CompilerPass.

Is it not possible to use the App cache as a tagged cache? I suppose I could create a separate pool and maybe use that, but it seems like a weird choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so obviously this is a config issue.

The following will work

```yaml
# services.yaml
  redis.cache_app:
    class: Redis
    factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
    arguments:
      - '%env(REDIS_DNS)%'

  cache.app.redis_tag_aware:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisTagAwareAdapter
    arguments:
      - '@redis.cache_app'
      - ''
      - 0
      - '@?cache.default_marshaller'
    calls:
      - ['setLogger', ['@?logger']]
    tags:
      - { name: cache.pool, provider: redis.cache_app, clearer: cache.default_clearer, reset: reset }
      - { name: monolog.logger, channel: cache }
```

```yaml
# cache.yaml
framework:
  cache:
    prefix_seed: !php/const App\Kernel::APP_VERSION
    app: cache.app.redis_tag_aware
```